# Как уменьшить аппетиты named?

Tags: linux, centos, производительность, ram, bind

Всем привет. Имеется небольшой VPS с весьма ограниченными ресурсами - всего 256Mb RAM.
На этот VPS под управлением операционной системы CentOS 7 я установил PHP 7.3, NginX и bind 9.9.4-74
Изучая вывод команды top я обратил внимание, что named занимает очень большой объем памяти RAM - 25.2%

```
PID  USER  PR NI VIRT   RES   SHR  S %CPU %MEM TIME+   COMMAND
1509 named 20 0  170804 61476 3260 S 0.0  25.2 0:00.24 named
```

Вот конфиг named.conf

```
acl "trusted" {
    127.0.0.1;
    SERVER_IP;
};

// these are just a list of ip's that I consider bogus and just ignore them
acl "fakeips" {
#        0.0.0.0/8;
};

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;SERVER_IP; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query { any; }; // Этот параметр указывает, кому разрешается подавать запросы к нашему серверу
    allow-query-cache { none; };
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    allow-notify { trusted; };
    allow-transfer { trusted; };
    version "not currently available";
    blackhole { fakeips; };

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Подскажите, есть ли способы уменьшить аппетиты named? Так, чтобы это не влияло на скорость VPS.

Comment: А может он не нужен на vps?  а может его кто то используется для  флуда?

Comment: KoVadim не понял ваш комментарий. Что значит не нужен? Для какого флуда?

Comment: в прямом смысле слова. Если named не используется, то может его остановить? нет named'а, нет нагрузки.

Comment: KoVadim, named на VPS конечно же нужен, а как иначе домены, которые я добавлю на VPS станут доступны в сети? Просто показалось очень странным, что named жрет столько оперативки - больше чем php и nginx вместе взятые, по идее он должен занимать в памяти совсем немного.

Comment: тогда открывайте его логи и смотрите, чем он там занимается

Comment: мелковата vps для "много доменов". может лучше перенести управление зоной к регмстратору или на pdd.yandex.ru какой-нибудь

Comment: ну у тебя всего 256м, т.е. он "жрёт" 25м - это совсем не много, если он работает.
скорее всего php и  nginx у тебя бездействуют, вот и нет нагрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй поэкспериментировать с настройкой max-cache-size установив её в пределах 2-20 мегабайт - 20m